# Set theory: infinite set proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove the following

Let $f: A \to B$ be a surjective function, where $B$ is an infinite set. If $f^{-1}(y)$ is finite or denumerable for each $y \in B$, prove that $A \approx B$.

I am stuck from the very beginning... Any hint would be greatly appreciated.
So I am guessing that I would need to show that $f$ is injective, then I will be done.

Comment: What does $A \approx B$ mean?

Comment: @Asemismaiel it means $A$ is equipotent to $B$

Comment: you can't show $f$ is injective because it may be false.

Comment: If $f^{-1}(y)$ is at most countable, you can well order this set and choose the least $x_y\in f^{-1}(y)$ for each $y$, so you can define a bijection.

Comment: Hint: $A = \bigsqcup_{y\in B} f^{-1}(\{y\})$.

Comment: If $f^{-1}(y)$ is finite or denumerable, then it can definitely be a set with more than one element, in which case $f$ is *not* injective.

Comment: @user160738: there may not be an order at all.

Comment: @Nick But if it's at most countable, then it can be bijected onto a subset of $\omega$, which then induces order on this set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $\;A\approx B\;$ actually means $\;|A|=|B|\;$ , i.e. both sets have the same cardinality. Observe that

$$A=\bigcup_{b\in B}f^{-1}(y)\;,\;$$

and clearly $\;b\neq b'\implies f^{-1}(b)\cap f^{-1}(b')=\emptyset\;$ , so in fact

$$|A|=\sum_{b\in B}|f^{-1}(b)|\le\aleph_0\cdot|B|=|B|$$

and since $\;f:A\to B\;$ is surjective, we also have that $\;|A|\ge|B|\;$ , so Schröder-Bernstein's Theorem ends the proof.

Comment: A proof of $\aleph_0\cdot |B|=|B|$ would be nice, imho it's the only not-trivial ingredient

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo DIdn't understand: what proof would be nice, again?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Oh, that. Well, that is true for any two infinite cardinals $\;\alpha,\,\beta\,,\,\,\alpha\le\beta\implies \alpha\beta=\beta\;$, and it is based on cardinal arithmetic and, again, S.B. theorem: since $\;|B|\;$ is infinite, we have that $\;|B|\ge\aleph_0\;$ , and then$$|B|\le\aleph_0|B|\le|B|^2=|B|$$ where the last equality follows in a similar way as how it is proved that $\;|\Bbb N^2|=\aleph_0\;$ ...

Comment: to prove $|B|^2=|B|$ we usually use zermelo right?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo I think that would be way too much, though if it is available it could, probably, make things easier. I'm not sure, and I don't remember right now, if it is necessary for that proof, but of the top of my head I'd say it isn't...

Comment: the fact that $|B\times B|=|B|$ is equivalent to choice in ZF and choice is equivalent to zermelo

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Well, there you have: you need it this or that way. Fine.